# Bluetooth keyboard pairs but does not appear as an input device?

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, external-keyboard

I purchased a bluetooth keyboard to use with my lenovo ideatab a2107 which runs android 4.0.3. The specific keyboard is the:

[Anker® Ultra Slim Bluetooth Wireless Keyboard for iPad Mini, iPad 4, New iPad 3, iPhone 5, Android 3.0 and above Tablet - Black](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0096M8VR2)

I am able to pair the keyboard with my tablet and the it has a keyboard icon next to it in the list of bluetooth devices. When this happens I am asked to type a 4 digit code and press enter on the keyboard. This works fine.

The Keyboard does not show up in tablet's keyboard & input devices list and I am unable to input text using the keyboard. How can I get the keyboard working properly with my tablet?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked it in your settings, if the input method is enabled (I'm not sure which list you mean, so this is just for clarification)?

Comment: I have checked this. The keyboard does not show up on the list of available input methods.

Answer (score 1):

Found a possible solution from [Android Central questions](http://forums.androidcentral.com/t-inspire-4g/81161-i-cant-pair-bluetooth-keyboard.html) give it a shot.

[Specifically, this post](http://forums.androidcentral.com/t-inspire-4g/81161-i-cant-pair-bluetooth-keyboard.html#post2136162) says to do the following:

> When pairing the keyboard with your device, it will prompt you to
>   enter a pin and say "try 0000 or 1234." You need to:
>
> Step 1) enter "0000" on your android device (tablet or phone
>   keyboard)
>  Step 2) hit "okay"
>  Step 3) type "0000" and hit enter
>   on your BLUETOOTH keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I'm using Apple wireless keyboard and Android ICS 4.0. I can pair and connect them both, but there is no additional IME in the input list. Checking and unchecking the `use as input` option does not change anything.

I'm not sure if there should be one but some say bluetooth keyboard is supported out of the box in ICS. Also, some YouTube videos show users who managed to connect them and typing right away without choosing any IME or anything.

I'm using BlueKeyboard JP (works well for me) for the time being until I find a way to get it work natively without a third-party app.

Answer (score 0):

Unpair it first and do it again inputting the requested numbers. Also unpair any other 'Bluetooth Keyboards' on the list. That worked for me.

Comment: 'Do it again', meaning try pairing it again.